# Passing Extra Parameter from form_for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, form-helpers

I have nested categories model which have `parent_id` attribute. I try to get data from dynamic select boxes. (I'm using ajax to get relational options)

`new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for :category, url: categories_path do |f| %>

Category 1: <%= f.collection_select(:parent_id, @categories, :id, :name, ) %>
Category 2: <%= f.collection_select(:parent_id, @categories, :id, :name ) %>
Category 3: <%= f.collection_select(:parent_id, @categories, :id, :name ) %>

    <p>
            <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, when someone choose one option from select boxes, the form push only the last option. I want to get each of them in one array like `:parent_id[]`

Here is my `new` and `update` actions from controller.

```ruby
def new
        @category = Category.new

        @categories = Category.roots
end

def create
 @category = Category.new(category_params)

 if @category.save

         redirect_to categories_path
 else
         render 'new'
 end
end
```

How can I get something like `:parent_id => [1 ,2, nil]` ?
I want to decide in controller which one I need to store.

Comment: I dont think thats possible with this piece of code where you are basically using the same name for all three select fields. check the generated html code from the browser, you will see all three are having the same name something like `parent_id[:id]` , I think you should choose different `name` for each field explicitly to get the value.

Comment: @Abhinay Thanks! for you comment. But how can i use an variable here which isn't in my model. Because I have just have parent_id, I haven't any array in my model. Do I have to use virtual attributes?

Comment: You just need to use different `name` for all three, i guess you can do something like `name: 'parent[id1]'` for first, `name: 'parent[id2]'` for second and `name: 'parent[id3]'` for third. and make sure to add these to your allowed params in Controller.

Comment: @Abhinay thanks, it worked. I understood how it is work.